# How to upload hdf5 files of huge size into google colab?

Tags: conv-neural-network, hdf5, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I have a hdf5 file (image dataset) of size 17GB which I need to upload and use in the Google Colab and train my model on this dataset. But however when I use the following code to upload from my drive the run time automatically gets disconnected after the authentication process. Is it because of the size of the file or other issues? Any solution/s for overcoming this?

The code snippet is below :

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

#Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Get the file
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'my_id'}) #replace the my_id with id of file you want to access
downloaded.GetContentFile('dataset.hdf5')
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem with importing hdf5 files to colab? Would you mind sharing a colab-notebook of your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

IF the dataset is from kaggle provide Colab with the git url and it will download it automatically. Else you are at the mercy of your internet connection.